# Kafka Connect. How to set batch size, which specifies when a part file should be closed and a new one started

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, apache-kafka-connect

I have a Flink Job which reads Kafka avro topics and writes files to HDFS.  To manage rolling file size I use sink setBatch size - [bucketing-file-sink](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/dev/connectors/filesystem_sink.html#bucketing-file-sink) https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/dev/connectors/filesystem_sink.html#bucketing-file-sink

```
sink.setBatchSize(1024 * 1024 * 400) // this is 400 MB,
```

I want to repeat the same with Kafka Connect and get files with equal size. Could you help me find the same parameter for managing file size?
I found only `flush.size` parameter which let me set the amount of records before the file should be closed and a new one started.
[Flush size](https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connect-hdfs/current/configuration_options.html#connector)

Answer (score 0):

There's no such property in the HDFS sink to flush by file size. [See related issue on Github](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-hdfs/issues/365)